# "Key-combination" synonym for "keyboard-shortcuts" tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

I think there should be `key-combination` synonym for [keyboard-shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) tag.